# Value of type 'double' cannot be converted to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell

Tags: c#, datagridview

I want to show a list in DataGridView but the error says:

> Cannot implicitly convert type double to `System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell`.

What should I do?

```
for (int i = 0; i < nlength; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0) data_result.Rows[i].Cells[0] =U[2 * i];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set the value of the cell, not the cell itself.
Look at [this msdn article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.value?view=netframework-4.7&WT.mc_id=docs-email) for more information

```
data_result.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = U[2 * i];
```